# How to avoid using global variables in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, global-variables

1. I have `/bin/www` that I execute and `websocketServer.js` that needs the `httpServer` object from `/bin/www` to initialize the websocket server. How can I pass `httpServer` to `websocketServer.js` without using a global variable?

websocketServer.js:

```
let WebSocket = require('ws')
let wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server: global.httpServer })
wss.on('connection', (connection, req) =>
...
```

/bin/www:

```
let app = require('../app')
let http = require('http')
...
global.httpServer = http.createServer(app)
httpServer.listen(port)
...
```

2. I have `foo.js` and `bar.js` that both handle user information that is only persistent at runtime (no need to store in database). How can these 2 files work with the same users? I can only think of using a shared variable aka global. Is there any way to avoid using a global variable in this situation? Should I even bother avoiding using global variables if it makes total sense to use them in my mind?
   Besides, I came to this situation of needing runtime global variables because so far I've been using a database which is essentially a provider of global variables. Except now my project requires variables that need to be global but *don't have to be stored in a database*.

foo.js:

```
...
function getsCalledWhenUserLogsIn(username)
{
    global.users[username] = { timer: new Timer(), websocketConnection: null, ... }
    // initializing the user below
    ...
}
...
```

bar.js:

```
...
websocketServer.on('connection', (connection, req) =>
{
    ...
    connection.on('message', (message) =>
    {
        let user = global.users[JSON.parse(message).username]
        if (user)
        {
            user.websocketConnection = connection
            ... 
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
...
```

This is not my code per se but at least it gives you some idea

I want to be able to structure my files in a way that I won't have to use global variables.

Comment: Can you include your code? I would say the common practice would be to parametrize the _websocketServer.js_ module to have it accept the httpServer as argument, but I can't write a proper answer without having any code to work with

Comment: @PatrickHund added some pseudocode to give you the idea

Answer (score 1):

Example with global variables:

```
global.bar = 'hello world';

function foo1() {
   console.log(bar);
}

function foo2() {
   console.log(bar);
}

foo1();
foo2();
```

Example without global variables:

```
var bar = 'hello world';

function foo1(bar) {
   console.log(bar);
}

function foo2(bar) {
   console.log(bar);
}

foo1(bar);
foo2(bar);
```

This is overly simplistic, but the main point is: if you want 2 distinct things to have access to the same object without being aware of each other, you need a 'third thing' to pass this object to the first two things.

Also see: dependency injection.

As for the question if you should always do this... I would argue that avoiding globals is something you should *always* strive for, unless you have a good reason not to. Best practices are a good default, but break them if common sense dictates that you shouldn't apply it for specific cases.

However, I don't think that you have a valid enough case for it here. You just have to learn functions and arguments a bit better.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid global variables you could use XMLHttpRequest and just GET/POST to yourself. Not the most efficient thing but it would still work.

```
var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr2.open('GET', "http://yourserver", true);
xhr2.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {
        if(this.responseText == '') { return;}
      //your code here
  }//
  };//end onreadystate
 xhr2.send();
```

You could also have global arrays that have objects and just go through them. Then you have one array. It just depends how you want to go about it.

Comment: This is definitely a case where using a global variable is better than the alternative. This is a pretty inventive, but terrible idea ;)

Comment: You didn't get it, did you? I don't want a shitty implementation of global variables. I want to be able to structure my files in a way that I won't need to use global variables

Comment: Well, I would say include some code and less snarky responses. And maybe we could help you out more.